# Anti-flood DDoS in PHP

Tags: php, ddos

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
}
// anti flood protection
if($_SESSION['last_session_request'] > time() - 2){
        // users will be redirected to this page if it makes requests faster than 2 seconds
        header("location: http://www.example.com/403.html");
        exit;
}
$_SESSION['last_session_request'] = time();
?>
```

I've already tested this script as you higher the second It Will keep redirecting to `http://www.example.com/403.html` without any reason.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Debugging tip: echo the variable before the if statement to make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: Try making your first line just be session_start() without the if statement

Comment: I've just tested this script - it works perfectly. It doesn't keep on redirecting for myself.

Comment: Well Higher seconds to 8 then it will keep redirecting

Answer (score 8):

Let's think about this logically for a second...

The attacker's request is already being sent to the web-server and through to the PHP script.
The bottle-neck which causes failure in DDoS attacks is the web-server.

The idea behind a DDoS attack is just that - to cause a denial of service, in which the website/server is unable to process any new requests. So in escense, this approach is irrational. 
You need to go up the ladder of request handling.

If you have a server to your disposal, it's *easier*. You could simply implement a rate limiting rule on the kernel firewall/iptables.
But assuming you do not have access to that, Apache is still at your disposal - although not as efficient.

Implementing a rule within .htaccess is a *better* solution, but still not perfect.
But depending on the DDoS attack, there's no real solution at the developer's disposal to block it.

Comment: then i have my own private server but iptables doesnt limit 6 requests per ip

Comment: Really? You can implement a rule set that will block x number of requests within x amount of second that have a certain state. See: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187

Comment: By The Way I have Already Tried This . i need to limit requests per ip automaticaly

Comment: Well there are plenty of articles out there, just google. :) https://www.google.com/search?q=rate+limit+with+iptables

Comment: i have saw as many articles but still having same problem. iptables configured properly though.

Comment: I suggest you open a question for that on ServerFault(with where, what & when) or somewhere. If you have access to do this on a OS/kernel level, there's no need to do it in PHP.

Comment: yes i have full access to my server but i couldnt find a way to limit request per ip. and i couldnt find a way with .htaccess also to limit requests

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a good anti-flood script that des not need cookies (perfect for webservices). It's not perfect against advanced DDOS attacks but it's enough for preventing beginners attacks and automatic multiple requests.

For using it, before it's needed to create "flood" folder with a "ctrl" file inside and a "lock" subfolder.  Also needed to be setted with correct permissions.

Already tested by me.

```
define("SCRIPT_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));

// number of allowed page requests for the user
define("CONTROL_MAX_REQUESTS", 3);
// time interval to start counting page requests (seconds)
define("CONTROL_REQ_TIMEOUT", 2);
// seconds to punish the user who has exceeded in doing requests
define("CONTROL_BAN_TIME", 5);
// writable directory to keep script data 
define("SCRIPT_TMP_DIR", SCRIPT_ROOT."/flood");
// you don't need to edit below this line
define("USER_IP", $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
define("CONTROL_DB", SCRIPT_TMP_DIR."/ctrl");
define("CONTROL_LOCK_DIR", SCRIPT_TMP_DIR."/lock");
define("CONTROL_LOCK_FILE", CONTROL_LOCK_DIR."/".md5(USER_IP));
@mkdir(CONTROL_LOCK_DIR);
@mkdir(SCRIPT_TMP_DIR);


if (file_exists(CONTROL_LOCK_FILE)) {
    if (time()-filemtime(CONTROL_LOCK_FILE) > CONTROL_BAN_TIME) {
        // this user has complete his punishment
        unlink(CONTROL_LOCK_FILE);
    } else {
        // too many requests
        echo "<h1>DENIED</h1>";
        echo "Please try later.";
        touch(CONTROL_LOCK_FILE);
        die;
    }
}

function antiflood_countaccess() {
    // counting requests and last access time
    $control = Array();

    if (file_exists(CONTROL_DB)) {
        $fh = fopen(CONTROL_DB, "r");
        $control = array_merge($control, unserialize(fread($fh, filesize(CONTROL_DB))));
        fclose($fh);
    }

    if (isset($control[USER_IP])) {
        if (time()-$control[USER_IP]["t"] < CONTROL_REQ_TIMEOUT) {
            $control[USER_IP]["c"]++;
        } else {
            $control[USER_IP]["c"] = 1;
        }
    } else {
        $control[USER_IP]["c"] = 1;
    }
    $control[USER_IP]["t"] = time();

    if ($control[USER_IP]["c"] >= CONTROL_MAX_REQUESTS) {
        // this user did too many requests within a very short period of time
        $fh = fopen(CONTROL_LOCK_FILE, "w");
        fwrite($fh, USER_IP);
        fclose($fh);
    }
    // writing updated control table
    $fh = fopen(CONTROL_DB, "w");
    fwrite($fh, serialize($control));
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Taken from here:  https://github.com/damog/planetalinux/blob/master/www/principal/suscripcion/lib/antiflood.hack.php

Answer (score 0):

just change `>` to `<`:

```
<?php        

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
}
// anti flood protection
if($_SESSION['last_session_request'] < time() - 2){
        // users will be redirected to this page if it makes requests faster than 2 seconds
        header("location: http://www.example.com/403.html");
        exit;
}
$_SESSION['last_session_request'] = time();
?>
```

Comment: This will redirect the user who make requests slower then 2 seconds.

Comment: wasn't that the problam at first?

Comment: i need to redirect user if he made more then 5 requests in 6 seconds

Comment: than you will have to save somewhere the time of the first request

Comment: I just need to fix this php script just to limit 5 requests in 6 seconds

Comment: An attacker can easily defeat this by not storing cookies.

Comment: @Olhovsky it's a session, i can't see how he can delete it. but yea it's an old answer and not a very good one, i'm sure there are much smarter solutions. and now when I look at it the question itself is not very good, and therefore the upvoted answer is absolutely better than mine.

Comment: @DanBarzilay PHP keeps track of the session in a cookie. What I'm saying is that you can just not provide the server with your session key.

Answer (score 0):

What spudinksi said still holds true, however here is what your looking for:

```
 <?php


 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
         session_start();
 }

 if($_SESSION['last_session_request'] > (time() - 5)){
    if(empty($_SESSION['last_request_count'])){
        $_SESSION['last_request_count'] = 1;
    }elseif($_SESSION['last_request_count'] < 5){
        $_SESSION['last_request_count'] = $_SESSION['last_request_count'] + 1;
    }elseif($_SESSION['last_request_count'] >= 5){
            header("location: http://www.example.com/403.html");
            exit;
         }
 }else{
    $_SESSION['last_request_count'] = 1;
 }

 $_SESSION['last_session_request'] = time();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For stop DDos add a null route for that ip, like this:

```
route add -host ???.???.???.??? reject
```

Comment: This doesn't actually "stop" a DDoS in any sense; it just ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script called [IOSec](http://technoturbine.com/how-to-prevent-dosflood-attacks-using-php/), which is quite old, but it might help.

Comment: That link is not active anymore

Answer (score 0):

This will count page reloads & also save time after 3 seconds ....
if it gives problems or to easy for newbies to bypass then leave comment..

```
if(empty($_SESSION['AFsys_time']) || $_SESSION['AFsys_time'] == '0') {
    $tGoal = time() + 3; // Pluss Seconds
    $_SESSION['AFsys_time'] = $tGoal;
}

if(empty($_SESSION['AFsys_pReloads']) || $_SESSION['AFsys_pReloads'] == 0 ) { $_SESSION['AFsys_pReloads'] = 1; } else { $_SESSION['AFsys_pReloads']++; };

if($_SESSION['AFsys_time'] < time()){
    $_SESSION['AFsys_time'] = 0; // Session Reset
    $_SESSION['AFsys_pReloads'] = 0; // Session Reset
}

if($_SESSION['AFsys_pReloads'] > '5' && $_SESSION['AFsys_time'] > time()){
    $_SESSION['AFsys_time'] = 0; // Session Reset
    $_SESSION['AFsys_pReloads'] = 0; // Session Reset
    header("location: http://www.example.com/403.html");
    exit; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this code not work for curl looping like this.  session will create again on every curl exec;

```
for ($i=0;$i<999999999999999;$i++){

    /**/
    $c=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,"URL YOU WANT ATTACK");
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE,TRUE);//dns
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);//get the header
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,10);//get the header
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_NOBODY,0);//and *only* get the header
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);//get the response as a string from curl_exec(), rather than echoing it
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,1);//don't use a cached version of the url
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' ));

    echo "\n $i";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Session may be not work, because we haven't session coockie.

I recommend such

```
$load = sys_getloadavg();
if ($load[0] > 20) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Too busy, try again later');
    die('Server too busy. Please try again later.');
}
```

Or you can

```
shell_exec('/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -j DROP -s ' . $ip);
```

for ddosing $ip

Comment: So in this case, as soon as the server load is over 20%... no one will access your server.... hmmmm i think not

Comment: @Mayhem Разберись, что такое load average и в чем он измеряется!